# Format text after specific document width

Tags: c#, string, printing, format

I am printing some text on a printer that have 60mm width papers.

I want to print the text so it will be like this :

```
Value1         Value2
Value1         Value2
Value1         Value2
Value1         Value2
Value1         Value2
Value1         Value2
```

The value2 should be right aligned.

Dont really know how to measure the 60mm paper so my values will fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some trial/error here because it depends on the DPI. What you can do is that you append spaces between `Value1` and `Value2` until it's where you want it to be.

If you know the DPI, you can calculate how much will fit into one line, remember though that "m" takes up more space then "i" so if you have "mmm" you might need less spaces than if you have "iii".